# If U contains A and B, and X is 80% of A, how much % is X in U?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's suppose that U is the universe set and it contains the sets A that is 60% of U and B that is 40% of U, so they are disjoints, the set A contains the set X that is 80% of A, how much in percent is X in U?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Draw a diagram.  Imagine that U has 100 elements.  How many are in A?  How many are in X?

Comment: I edited the question adding the details I forgot about A and B.

Comment: A is 60%, B is 40%, and they are disjoint sets.

Answer (score 0):

$$
{80\times 60 \over 100}\ \% = \color{#ff0000}{\large 48 \%}.
$$